# Two code snippet icons in "Improve Edit" or "Reject and Edit" editors

Tags: bug, status-completed, suggested-edits, stack-snippets

When someone suggest edit we can see it in review queue, or by post itself by clicking `edit` option which will be marked `edit(1)`. But if I use `edit(1)` from under the post and press one of <kbd>Improve Edit</kbd> or <kbd>Reject and Edit</kbd> options, editor will contain ***two*** code snippet icons:

[image]

---

If I use <kbd>Improve Edit</kbd> or <kbd>Reject and Edit</kbd> options from [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review) queue everything seems to be fine (only one icon is shown for code snippet).

[image]

Comment: One lets you insert code snippets. The other presents you with a #2 pencil and an Iowa Test of Basic Skills.

Comment: OK, thanks. Should I delete this question or do you want to leave it to let others with similar question find it? If it should stay then consider posting your comment as an answer.

Comment: I'm joking - ITBS is/was a paper-based Scantron test. This is legitimately a bug, please leave it here for Haney.

Comment: Ha ha it is really late where I leave now so I assumed (actually without reading) that if @Shog9 is giving explanation it must be true. It means it is time to sleep. Good night everyone :)

Comment: Be careful who you trust, especially folks who answer confidently without hesitation. Sleep well!

Comment: I was just about to report this. The insert into post button didn't work, when I clicked outside the snippet window, It turned white making the page in accessible... I had to abandon a bit long edit and do it all over again...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Turns out the snippets editor not working was just the tip of the iceberg. The suggested edit review popup + `improve edit`/`reject and edit` was a big can of <strike>worms</strike> bugs. Even the `hyperlink` and `image` editor tools were extremely quirky inside that popup, especially the background lightbox click & <kbd>esc</kbd> key handling.

A fix for all of the above went out with build rev `2015.1.21.2979` on meta and `2015.1.21.2205` on sites.