# Bug in improve edit process creates multiple code snippet icons

Tags: bug, suggested-edits, stack-snippets

I won't go into details about why I ended up going through this route, but to reproduce the bug, find any question or answer that has a pending suggested edit. Choose the <kbd>Improve Edit</kbd> button, click the cancel link, then click the <kbd>Skip</kbd> button. Then click the <kbd>Improve Edit</kbd> button again. For every time you go through this process, another code snippet icon is added to the toolbar.
[image]

This is similar to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272639/two-code-snippet-icons-in-improve-edit-or-reject-and-edit-editors) question, however that question indicates that it doesn't happen in the review queue, which makes sense because pressing the skip button would send you onto a different question.